# Drawing an svg containing html in a canvas with safari

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, safari

I'm trying to create some thumbnails of dynamically created pages for a website, i have found a solution by adding the html in a svg which I then draw on an image inside a canvas that I resize after the image has been drawn.

This solution works in firefox and chrome but not in safari, the svg doesn't seem to be drawn I just get a blank page. I don't get any error even if i put some try catch and I couldn't find a solution on the web.

My html is just a basic test page with a canvas, I tried to add a meta tag on the head

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
```

but it didn't work either.

Here's the code I wrote :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasTest'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
                 "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
                   "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>" +
                     "<div>TEST<span>TEST</span></div>" +
                   "</div>" +
                 "</foreignObject>" +
               "</svg>"
            ;

            var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
            var img = new Image();                                                                              

            try {
                var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});                      
            } catch(e) {                    
                window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder || window.MSBlobBuilder;
                console.log(window.BlobBuilder);

                if(e.name == 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder){
                    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
                    bb.append(data);
                    var svg = bb.getBlob("image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8");
                } else if(e.name == "InvalidStateError") {                      
                    var svg = new Blob(data, {type : "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
                } else {

                }
            }               

            var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);              

            img.onload = function() {                   
                    context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);                                       
            };

            img.src = url;
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

            context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            context.scale(0.4, 0.4);
```

Safari can use the Blob constructor so it doesn't go in the catch. It seems like the problem is when I pass the svg reference (img.src = url) but i can't figure out what to do differently, if someone has some ideas or solution it would be great.

Edit: console output for safari

Blob: Blob {size=232, type="image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8", webkitSlice}

Url: blob:http://myPage.com/96fb502f-46bb-492b-af35-5313bb39bd31

Comment: Can you use `.toDataURL()` afterwards, or do you get a Security Error on Safari ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically the solution was to put the mime type(data:image/svg+xml) in the variable containing the svg, this way you don't need to use the blob anymore and then to set the img src with the svg before drawing it to the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasTest'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var data = "data:image/svg+xml,"+"<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
                 "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
                   "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>" +
                     "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>aaaa<span>aaaa</span></div>" +
                   "</div>" +
                 "</foreignObject>" +
               "</svg>"
            ;

            var img = new Image();

            img.src = data;

            img.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);                   
            };

            context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            context.scale(0.4, 0.4);
```

Comment: Bloody genius! Thanks you for the super-simple example. I had some code that was working in Chrome and FF, but not in Safari. It was using the window.URL object and using that to create a blob, and then drawing the blob to the canvas. Your example here is much simpler, and it works in Safari as well as the other browsers that I need to support. Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to say `var data = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + encodeURIComponent(svgElementCode);` instead, for utf-8 and better browser support. [See here](http://codepen.io/RwwL/pen/Aczds).

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what you get in console on the Blob nor the URL.

Just a shot but you are revoking the url right after setting it as source on the image. You need to revoke if *after* the image has been loaded in the `onload` event:

```
img.onload = function() {                   
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);      /// here
    context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);                                       
};

img.src = url;
//DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);        /// not here
```

See that helps out. If not then you're probably dealing with a Safari specific issue.
(your canvas specific translate etc. should also be inside the `onload` event or at least called before you set the `src` property).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solutions but i still get a blank page on safari. I have edited my question to include the console output for the blob and url. Do you have any more idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: I have finally found a solution which works for ff chrome and safari, i will post it later. Thanks for your answer i upvoted you for the help