# DOM Exception: SECURITY_ERR (18) when using getImageData

Tags: javascript, svg

I just started getting this error when I switched from using png images to SVG. The images are on the same server that I am running this code on -

```
function getLeftEdge(myImage) {
        var img = document.getElementById(myImage);
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var pixelData;

        for (var x = 0; x < tmp[0]; x++) {
            for (var y = 0; y < tmp[1]; y++) {
                pixelData = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
```

So this shouldn't be a cross domain issue. I don't think. I created the SVG images using ImageMagick to convert the png images on a Linux machine at another domain. Could that cause this somehow? I can't see anything in the SVG file header that identifies where it came from.

I found this, http://enable-cors.org/, about changing my server but I would really like to find a way to clean up the images because the program and images will be sent on to a customer to use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the `<img>` tags have "src" attributes that load from a domain different from the host page?

Comment: No, here is the img tag <img class='img-responsive' id='1fp' src='images/508/1fp.svg' alt='floor plan'>

Comment: Is the image coming from *your* domain or some other domain?

Comment: Like I said above, I made it at another domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an SVG file taints the canvas regardless of the domain in Chrome and Safari.

This link may help better explain. http://one-day-from.blogspot.com/2013/09/svg-in-html-5-canvas-tainted-canvas.html?m=1

EDIT:

I created a test case of the best possible scenario with SVG and Canvas. We use an inline SVG element to avoid any domain issues (uses sample code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas and [Drawing an svg containing html in a canvas with safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049179/drawing-an-svg-containing-html-in-a-canvas-with-safari))

https://jsfiddle.net/ydcbw56s/4/

the test is done in this line:

```
console.log(ctx.getImageData(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

- Chrome throws the error.
- Safari throws the error.
- Firefox gets the resulting pixel data.

Comment: Using SVG does not taint the canvas on Firefox.

Comment: So what is the work around? This seems like a huge issue to me. SVG files break javascript?

Comment: You could always look into converting the SVG paths to canvas paths. I'm not sure how simple or complicated these SVG files are but try this  http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent cross-domain image processing (which could allow an attacker to examine CAPTCHA images, for example), browsers keep track of the source of image data. If you populate a canvas with image data that the browser doesn't think your page should be able to "look at", then it won't let you call `.getImageData()`.

Normal cross-domain rules apply: images have to be from the exact same domain and port.

Comment: How does it know that I made these some place else?

Comment: Then why did this work when the image was a PNG image?

Comment: @user1601513 I don't know; that's a good question. It's not about where the images were *made*, it's about where the source URL is.